# Linear model with constraints

Tags: r, regression, contrasts

I'm quite new to R and I have a following problem:

I have a simple 2-factor linear model:

```
# factor1 has 8 categorical values, factor2 has 6 categories
Rate ~ factor1 + factor2 
model1 <- lm(Rate~factor1+factor2, data=myData)
```

And want to put constraints SUM of factor1 coefficients = 0, the same for factor2.

None of the manuals gives any clue how to do this.

I found a link to similar problem here but it is different and I couldnt figure out how to modify it...

Comment: Please **do not crosspost** simultaneously here and on SO.

Comment: Certainly, Sir :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using contrasts:

```
options(contrasts=c('contr.sum', 'contr.sum'))
```

See `?contr.sum` for more information.

UPDATE: A little googling reveals a page which might be a little clearer:

- Samuel E. Buttrey, [Setting and Keeping Contrasts](http://faculty.nps.edu/sebuttre/home/R/contrasts.html)

Comment: Thanks! It did work, question: it did not force the condition that coefficients sum up to 0, but minimized the sums for both factors. Is there a way to force the ==0 condition, or it simply does not do that since it would affect the error ?

Comment: @Vytautas: I think you're forgetting the reference level for your factor which is not shown (since it's the baseline for the others).

Comment: @Vytautas or take a look at *Interpreting model matrix columns when using contr.sum*, http://j.mp/9pNFQe.

Answer (score 22):

There is a trick to be had here. For simplicity, suppose you are trying to build a model of the form $$y = b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_3,$$ subject to $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0$. Simply re-express $b_3$ as $b_3 = - b_1 - b_2$, which is to say you are trying to build a model of the form
$$y = b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 - (b_1 + b_2) x_3 = b_1 (x_1 - x_3) + b_2 (x_2 - x_3).$$
So create new variables $\tilde{x}_1 = x_1 - x_3,$ and $\tilde{x}_2 = x_2 - x_3$, and perform your regression using these transformed variables as the independent variables.

You should be able to apply this trick independently to the catgories of `factor1` and `factor2`. (I have assumed the data is given as 0/1 indicators of membership in the individual categories.)

Comment: Huh, factors are well handled using the `factor` command, so no need to rely on dummy coding (otherwise, it's accessible through `model.matrix(lm(x~a*b))` for my toy example).

Comment: @chl thanks. I know very little R, but suspected this simple algebraic trick could be applied in any case, or at least illustrate what is going on 'under the hood'

Comment: Yes, definitely! this was just a precision. (and you have my +1)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is to use the appropriate [built-in function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/contrast.html):

```
myContrasts <- list(factor1=contr.sum(length(levels(factor1))),
                    factor2=contr.sum(length(levels(factor2))))

model1 <- lm(Rate ~ factor1 + factor2, data=myData, contrasts=myContrasts)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are packages for it.

One example is [glmc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmc/index.html) - Generalized Linear Models Subject to Constraints.

See documentation here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmc/glmc.pdf

A good overview on optimisation techniques with the use of constraints can be found here:
http://zoonek.free.fr/blosxom/R/2012-06-01_Optimization.html

Example code (from the glmc documentaion):

```
library(glmc)
#Specify the data.
n <- rbind(c(5903,230),c(5157,350))
mat <- matrix(0,nrow=sum(n),ncol=2)
mat <- rbind(matrix(1,nrow=n[1,1],ncol=1)%*%c(0,0),
matrix(1,nrow=n[1,2],ncol=1)%*%c(0,1),
matrix(1,nrow=n[2,1],ncol=1)%*%c(1,0),
matrix(1,nrow=n[2,2],ncol=1)%*%c(1,1))
#Specifying the population constraints.
gfr <- .06179*matrix(1,nrow=nrow(mat),ncol=1)
g <- matrix(1,nrow=nrow(mat),ncol=1)

amat <- matrix(mat[,2]*g-gfr,ncol=1)

hrh <- data.frame(birth=mat[,2], child=mat[,1], constraints=amat)
gfit <- glmc(birth~child, data=hrh, family="binomial",emplik.method="Owen",
control=glmc.control(maxit.glm=10,maxit.weights=200,
itertrace.weights=TRUE,gradtol.weights=10^(-6)))
summary.glmc(gfit)
```